# Training done, certificate received, should I put it on my cv/linkedin profile?

Tags: resume, linkedin, training, certification

Recently I had a four-day training about Android development. The training was paid by my employer and delivered by an external company.

It's the first time I've taken this kind of training. Sincerely I'm not a hardcore coder anymore, so I don't think that tomorrow I will start working as an Android developer. I enjoyed the training and the coding part, but I think that my current role pays better than being a junior developer. This is true even if mobile development is very interesting.

So, career-wise, I don't think that advertising this training makes much sense (beside showing how flexible I'm). On the other hand, it's the first time I took such a training class and I found it very interesting.

Does it make sense to add this information (I had an Android training with this training company) to my cv/linkedin?

about me:
I work as Business Intelligence Tech Lead. What I mostly do is work with SQL databases, BI tools and integration with other applications. So for now Android is not really useful.

Comment: I think that you have answered your own question. This training is not useful for your current job or future aspirations.

Answer (score 3):

Leave it off. If you don't want to do Android, it shouldn't be on your resume. Also, if you resume said you took a class about Android recently, it is fair game to ask you about Android at the interview. Which is certainly not what you want the focus to be.

You'll learn many things that aren't related to your job. It's ok. You don't have to list everything on the resume. It's not documentation of everything you have ever done.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think anyone is going to hire you as an Android developer based on the four-day course you took. On the other hand, if you were a PM in charge of an Android development project, I can see how your training could be useful in helping you interact effectively with the developers. However, at this point, you're not functioning as a PM.

I don't think it's worthwhile for you to include it on your CV at this point, because I figure you'll forget most of the material within 30 days, unless you receive additional training that reinforces your current level of knowledge :)

In general, be conservative about adding stuff that distracts from the focus of your resume where the focus of your resume is the implicit message about your education, your work experience that you want to send to whoever is reading your resume.